# strange behaviour while creating NFS datastore on load balanced servers

Tags: vmware-esxi, load-balancing, nfs, lvs, datastore

> BACKGROUND

- vSphere client version = 5.1.0
- VMWare ESXi version = 5.1.0
- Server OS = RHEL version 6.8
- virtualip = virtual IP
- server1 = ip address of server 1
- server2 = ip address of server 2
- lvsserver = ip address of lvs router
- IPVSADM rules

  - ipvsadm -A -t virtualip:0 -s rr -p
  - ipvsadm -a -t virtualip:0 -r server2:0 -g
  - ipvsadm -a -t virtualip:0 -r server1:0 -g
  - ipvsadm -A -t virtualip:2049 -s rr
  - ipvsadm -a -t virtualip:2049 -r server1:2049 -g
  - ipvsadm -a -t virtualip:2049 -r server2:2049 -g

**/etc/exports** on both servers (server1, server2)

```
/vm0    *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

**Both servers contains /vm0 folder**

> ACTUAL PROBLEM
>
> scenario 1: on server1

```
root@server1 ~# mount -t nfs server2:/vm0 /vm0
root@server1 ~# service nfs restart
```

tried to create NFS datastore using following credentials

```
server = virtualip
Folder = /vm0
Datastore name = vm0
```

**RESULT success!**

> scenario 2:

```
//ON SERVER 1
    root@server1 ~# umount vm0

//ON SERVER 2
    root@server2 ~# mount -t nfs server1:/vm0 /vm0
    root@server2 ~# service nfs restart
```

tried to create NFS datastore using following credentials

server = virtualip
Folder = /vmo
Datastore name = vm0
RESULT Failed!

**ERROR MESSAGE on ESXi server**

> Call "HostDatastoreSystem.CreateNasDatastore" for object "ha-datastoresystem" on ESXi (ESXi_ip) failed.
> NFS mount (virtualip):/vm0 failed: The mount request was denied by the NFS server. Check that the export exists and that the client is permitted to mount it.

**logs traced using tshark**

> 33.916294107 (virtualip) -> (ESXi_ip) MOUNT 100 V3 MNT Reply (Call In 41) Error:ERR_ACCESS

Comment: I'm sorry. This doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do? Why are you using a load balancer for ESXi datastores and NFS?

Comment: @ewwhite actually, I want to achieve the load balancing while creating ESXi datastores for NFS. I am expecting that whenever I try to create the NFS datastore, everytime different server (server1 or server2) should do it.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Why would you want load-balanced datastores? VMware is not intended to work that way.

Comment: @ewwhite yes. you are right. but, I am trying to load balance the load-balance the **requests** and not the **datastore**.... and I am testing this setup using ESXi datastore as of now. to be exact, I need to load balance the NFS requests and ESXi is the only option that I have currently.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

All the NFS datastore requests to EXSi server are actually sent through VIP only (same IP everytime), this caused ESXi to use the cached information every time.

**Solution:**

use file system id (FSID) for all the intries in the /etc/exports file.
eg:

```
/<mount_folder> *(rw,sync,no_root_squash, fsid=1000)
```